# Change a number into a word inside a table

Tags: python, numbers, words

I have to write a program that outputs the numbers 1-100. In this kind of format:

```
 1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81   91
 2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82   92
 3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83   93
 4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84   94
 5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85   95
 6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86   96
 7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87   97
 8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88   98
 9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89   99
10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```

That's not the problem but in the next Step I have to replace each number that can be divided by 3 or contains a 3 into a specific word. Biff in my case. So the output should look like this:

```
   1   11 Biff Biff   41 Biff   61   71 Biff   91
   2 Biff   22 Biff Biff   52   62 Biff   82   92
Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff
   4   14 Biff Biff   44 Biff   64   74 Biff   94
   5 Biff   25 Biff Biff   55   65 Biff   85   95
Biff   16   26 Biff   46   56 Biff   76   86 Biff
   7   17 Biff Biff   47 Biff   67   77 Biff   97
   8 Biff   28 Biff Biff   58   68 Biff   88   98
Biff   19   29 Biff   49   59 Biff   79   89 Biff
  10   20 Biff   40   50 Biff   70   80 Biff  100
```

And that's where I'm stuck. Right now my code looks like this:

```
number=1
while number< 11:
    if (number % 3 == 0):
        print("Biff")
        number +=1
    else:
        print('{0:4d} {1:4d} {2:4d} {3:4d} {4:4d} {5:4d} {6:4d} {7:4d} {8:4d} {9:4d}'.format(number, number+10, number+20, number+30, number+40, number+50, number+60, number+70, number+80, number+90))
        number +=1
```

And the output looks like this:

```
   1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81   91
   2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82   92
Biff
   4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84   94
   5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85   95
Biff
   7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87   97
   8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88   98
Biff
  10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```

I'm trying to replace the numbers that can be divided by 3. But instead of replacing the single number it's replacing the whole line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my modification of your code:

```
for number in range(1, 11):
    line_contents = []
    for j in range(10):
        n = number + j * 10
        if (n % 3 == 0):
            line_contents.append("Biff")
        else:
            line_contents.append("{0:4d}".format(n))
    print(" ".join(line_contents))
```

This gives me:

```
   1   11 Biff   31   41 Biff   61   71 Biff   91
   2 Biff   22   32 Biff   52   62 Biff   82   92
Biff   13   23 Biff   43   53 Biff   73   83 Biff
   4   14 Biff   34   44 Biff   64   74 Biff   94
   5 Biff   25   35 Biff   55   65 Biff   85   95
Biff   16   26 Biff   46   56 Biff   76   86 Biff
   7   17 Biff   37   47 Biff   67   77 Biff   97
   8 Biff   28   38 Biff   58   68 Biff   88   98
Biff   19   29 Biff   49   59 Biff   79   89 Biff
  10   20 Biff   40   50 Biff   70   80 Biff  100
```

The key change is to have a variable `n` that contains each number in turn and to test whether this is divisible by 3. You were simply testing whether `number` was divisible by 3, i.e. only the number at the beginning of the line.

I've also tried to tidy up how you generate each line by storing a list of strings and building these up in an inner loop. After each inner loop I [concatenate the strings](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/joining_lists.html) and print the result.

Feel free to ask about any parts that aren't clear.

Comment: I've just re-read your question and seen the "or contains a 3" part. I'll add that if you need but I would encourage you to try and get it working yourself first.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your help. That's what I thought, but I couldn't find a solution. I've put some brackets after the print and at the end of the code, because I'm using Python 3 and it works perfectly fine. Now I should be able to do the remaining coding :) Again thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        n = 1+i+j*10
        print "{0:4d}".format(n) if (n) % 3 != 0 and  '3' not in str(n) else "Biff",
    print
```

gives

```
$ python t.py 
   1   11 Biff Biff   41 Biff   61   71 Biff   91
   2 Biff   22 Biff Biff   52   62 Biff   82   92
Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff Biff
   4   14 Biff Biff   44 Biff   64   74 Biff   94
   5 Biff   25 Biff Biff   55   65 Biff   85   95
Biff   16   26 Biff   46   56 Biff   76   86 Biff
   7   17 Biff Biff   47 Biff   67   77 Biff   97
   8 Biff   28 Biff Biff   58   68 Biff   88   98
Biff   19   29 Biff   49   59 Biff   79   89 Biff
  10   20 Biff   40   50 Biff   70   80 Biff  100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x: x * (x % 3 == 0) or "Biff", you_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
entries = ['Biff' if n % 3 == 0 or n % 10 == 3 else '{:4d}'.format(n) for n in range(1, 101)]

for row in range(10):
    print(' '.join(e for e in entries[row::10]))
```